# wpcf7_before_send_mail post form hangs and nothing happens

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying almost everything I see around the web, but noway :(

This is the function I'm trying to implement:

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail','save_to_db');

function save_to_db($cf7) {
$metakey    = "Harriet's Adages";
$metavalue  = "WordPress' database interface is like Sunday Morning: Easy.";

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
"
    INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta
    ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value )
    VALUES ( %d, %s, %s )
", 
    10, 
$metakey, 
$metavalue 
) );
}
```

I'm following [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) steps in order to make it work but when I click submit, the "sending icon" tourns for ever.., Any Idea? Thanks in advance!

PD: I'm stting up this code in functions.php of Twenty Twelve v 1.2 in a 3.6.1 Wordpress Version-
PD2: yes the data is not form CF7, I'm trying this from 0, so first goal is to save static data on DB.

Answer (score 0):

Well, its not a code solution, but this plugin does exacty what I need and it does exactly how I need:

[Flamingo](http://wordpress.org/plugins/flamingo/)